# How to update data with CodeIgniter and REST

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I am new to CodeIgniter. I want to create a web service REST for the update.

This is my controller:

```
function user_post()  
{  
    $result = $this->user_model->update( $this->get('id'),
        'name' => $this->post('name'));  

    if($result === FALSE)  
    {  
        $this->response(array('status' => 'failed'));  
    }  

    else  
    {  
        $this->response(array('status' => 'success'));  
    }  

}
```

And this function is in my model:

```
function update($id, $name)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE  user SET  name=? WHERE id=?";
    $this->db->query($sql, array($name,$id));
}
```

When I call the function by 
`index.php/exemple/user/id/1?method=post/name=Bill` it's not working.
Any idea please?

Comment: how is not working? what is the output?
and i think you should read ; [CI URLS](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `$result` in your controller will not be assigned a value. You need to add a `return` statement to the `update` function in your model:

```
function update($id, $name)
{
    $sql = "UPDATE  user SET  name=? WHERE id=?";
    return $this->db->query($sql, array($name,$id));
}
```